# Prevent image caching in leaflet popup?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, leaflet, folium

So I have a Python web service that creates maps with Folium/Leaflet.js. Each plotted point is a marker with a custom popup:

```
folium.Marker(
            location=(row['lat'], row['lng']),
            icon=folium.Icon(color=color_mapper[type]),
            popup=folium.Popup(f'<p>{info_str} taken at {row["time"]} <br> \
                                    Description: {row["description"]}</p> \
                                    <img src={row["photoURL"]} width=300 height=500>'),
                tooltip=info_str
)
```

At current the generated HTML map attempts to preload all image URLs provided in the  tag. This can get disastrous with 3GB+ of images being loaded, delaying the loading of the map tiles and data points.

Question: **Is there a way to stop the HTML from pre-caching the images within the popups, and only load the image when the popup is opened?**

I thought of some js script I could inject into the page after generation and before uploading to our CDN to alter the behavior, but so far my efforts have been fruitless in building this.

Comment: any luck with that? I have the same issue